# CruiseControl.NET with multiple SourceSafe databases

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to configure CruiseControl.NET and have come across an issue with SourceSafe. When ccnet builds I am getting the error:

> **No VSS database (srcsafe.ini) found.
>   Set the SSDIR environment variable to
>   the path of srcsafe.ini for your VSS
>   database**

I understand that setting the SSDIR environment variable would solve this immediate problem, however I don't believe that this should be necessary as I have specified it in my ccnet.config file. In my mind, setting the environment variable would limit ccnet to only ever use one SourceSafe database for all projects

I am running ccnet as a windows service and is using the same username and password that I would use to log onto the machine.

Below is the sourcecontrol section from my ccnet.config file:

```
    <sourcecontrol type="vss">
        <ssdir>S:\DotNet\</ssdir>
        <project>$/Web/Silverlight/SilverlightFramework</project>
        <username>ccnet</username>
        <password></password>
        <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
        <workingDirectory>D:\Build\Projects\SilverlightFramework\WorkingDirectory</workingDirectory>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the user I was running the ccnet service as did not have read access to the ssdir location specified.

This was a bit misleading because I could get to the location using the mapped directory S:\ under the same username but presumably this was due to windows having stored cached credentials from when the drive was mapped.